# Showing that two elements generate $\mathbb Z[\frac13] \rtimes \mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, semidirect-product

> Let $\mathbb Z$ act on the additive group $\mathbb Z\left[\frac13\right] = \{a/3^k : a \in \mathbb Z, k \ge 0\}$ by $\varphi_n(r) = 3^n r$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $r \in \mathbb Z\left[\frac13\right]$.  Let $G = \mathbb Z\left[\frac13\right] \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb Z$, a semi-direct product.
>
> (a) Compute the product $(r, m)(s, n)$ and the inverse $(r, m)^{-1}$ in the group $G$.
>
> (b) Show $G$ is generated by $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.

I found part (a) to be easy; $(r, m)(s, n) = (3^ms + r, m + n)$ and $(r, m)^{-1} = (-r3^{-m}, -m)$.  I'm struggling much more with part (b).  In fact, any time I need to show that two elements generate a group, I tend to have trouble figuring out what to do.  Any help on both solving this problem and any advice on how to show two elements generate a group would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by observing that multiples of $(1,0)$ give you all the $(r,0)$. Similarly multiplyes of $(0,1)$ all the $(0,n)$. Therefore you get all of $(r,0)(0,n)=(r,n)$. What's missing? The powers of three in the denominator. Well, what happens if you conjugate $(1,0)$ by powers of $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you can achieve $(a, 0)$ and $(0,n)$ for $a, n\in\mathbb Z$ as multiples of these generators. What if you want to get $(a/3^k,n)$? By definition of the semidirect product, $(0,k)(a, 0)(0,-k)=(a/3^k,0)$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As an aside, is this a typical strategy for approaching these problems?  I find it unlikely I would have done this on my own.

Comment: @gravity Unfortunately it varies by case. Sometimes it can be demonstrated abstractly, whereas other times you need to do specific calculations like this. I can't think of any general advice.